# jQuery Error in IE 8: Message: 'this.0.ownerDocument.body' is null or not an objec

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, ***PLEASE***: This specific error is not addressed in any other post on StackOverflow, so please do not mark this as a duplicate unless you can kindly post a link to the solution.

Version: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.5.2

Message: 'this.0.ownerDocument.body' is null or not an object
Line: 409
Char: 62
Code: 0
URI: http://<our-domain>/lib/js/jquery.min.js

First question: How do I debug something in jQuery itself? (Assuming I was to become that brave...)

Second: How can I determine what part of which of the myriad javascript & jquery files we use is triggering this error?

Comment: Have you made changes to the core?
Have you tried getting a fresh or newer copy of jQuery?
Can you provide us a link to test your ver?

Comment: A quick google search on this.0.ownerDocument.body indicates that offset() calls may be the first thing you should look at.

Comment: 1) No changes to the core.
2) Yes, we do offset params. Could you provide the link to the site where you found this? 'Cause I couldn't find it.  :-)

Comment: Rats! Removing the offset did not solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

> First question: How do I debug something in jQuery itself? (Assuming I was to become that brave...)

Place a breakpoint... And don't use the minified version.

Anyway, don't debug jQuery, it works very well, Your problem isn't almost for sure in your code, not their...

Comment: This also answers the second question - you'll have to place breakpoints in any scripts that could be leading to the error, and step forward until you locate it.

Comment: @Dave. With tools like VS, you can see the call-stack to know where did you come from.